# Server no longer responsive after reboot

Tags: linux, reboot

I changed my fstab into this:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Sat Jan 12 02:12:44 2013
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=fb2b6c2e-a8d7-4855-b109-c9717264da8a /                       ext4    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults        1 1
UUID=71362665-f627-41e1-a093-de42a0a356e2 /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
UUID=8024a5cd-af4b-4776-af0d-65ad80af8649 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/usr/tmpDSK             /tmp                    ext3    defaults,noauto        0 0
/dev/sdd1               /home4                  auto    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults        0 0
/dev/sdc1               /home3                  auto    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb1               /home2                  auto    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults        0 0
```

Basically the boot sector remains ext3. I disabled journaling for most drives because it causes heavy writes.

Now after rebooting server I can't even access ssh.

The message I got from ssh is connection refused.

Comment: From what I am understanding, and excuse me if I am wrong, but you think that your server is not coming up thus resulting in the inability to ssh into it? The error can be caused by multiple things. Can you ping the server and does it respond? Do you have physical access to the machine?

Comment: Do you have anohter account on the server to test ssh? Maybe you disable root login for ssh.

Comment: ssh ing is refused before I specify the user name. I can ping and tracert.

Comment: Do you have remote terminal access? There are too many possibilities and difficult to give suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am spotting one potential issue with your fstab, which may also answer your other 2 fstab questions.

Both `noload` AND `data=ordered` are useed on the same device.

1. `noload` basically means don't load/use journal
2. `data=ordered` set journal mode to `ordered`

So (1) is telling system to don't use journal but (2) is setting up journal mode, conflicting each other.

I cannot be 100% sure if the two option together is actually causing the problem as I don't want to test it on my VM.

Comment: however, I can mount /home2 and /home3 just fine without complain

Comment: hmm, maybe I will try it on a spare one later.